# Folding for git merge candidates is (at least to me) backwards

Tags: git

When viewing a merge candidate created by git you will have something like

```
. . .
Some stuff not in conflict
<<<<<< HEAD  
Some stuff  
======
Something different
>>>>>> devel
Some more stuff not in conflict
<<<<<< HEAD
. . .
```

For me at least, Vim tries to fold out the conflict so it looks like

```
. . .
Some stuff not in conflict
[fold here][<<<<<< HEAD]
Some more stuff not in conflict
[another fold][<<<<<< HEAD]
. . .
```

I don't really care about the stuff not in conflict. I'm looking at the file because I want to resolve the conflict which means I need to look at it. Instead `Some stuff not in conflict` and `Some more stuff not in conflict` should be folded out so I can focus on the conflicts. In other words, I want the exact opposite. Preferably, I'd like some context, but I'll take what I can get.

How do I do that?

More info:

```
:verbose set foldmethod? foldexpr? syntax? filetype?
foldmethod=manual
        Last set from /usr/share/vim/vimfiles/plugin/SyntaxFolds.vim line 134
  foldexpr=0
  syntax=tex
        Last set from /usr/share/vim/vim81/syntax/syntax.vim line 32
  filetype=tex
        Last set from /usr/share/vim/vim81/autoload/dist/ft.vim line 695
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but that command returns an error for me. Both as a whole and individually. I also tried without verbose. I have no clue why that isn't working.

Comment: Thanks. I edited the question.

Comment: Have you tried editing `SyntaxFolds.vim` to disable the match for the stuff in conflict and a new expression for the stuff not in conflict?

Comment: @Steve I have not, but I will this evening. Thanks.

Comment: @Steve Looking into your suggestion, I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: I haven't modified that language so can't be specific but when I was defining my own matches this helped in identifying what was under the cursor and would help identify what to comment out. https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Identify_the_syntax_highlighting_group_used_at_the_cursor .  I don't know what expression for tex would match the parts not folded so can't suggest one.